# What are the benefits, if any, of redirecting a blog/product category page to a static page?

Tags: seo, static-content, categories

When it comes to organising a website's layout, I see a lot of resources advising to redirect blog/product category pages to static pages.  This static page then becoming the 'parent category' for the subsequent child posts.

What benefit would this achieve, from an SEO perspective?  I have thought about this and I do not see any purposeful reason in doing this; other than editorial & creative (adding media etc.).

If the only benefit is editorial and/or creative, then why not create a category template and assign it the relevant functionalities?  To me, this makes greater logical sense; especially if you are using a CMS like WordPress.

**Update (07/05/2018 at 00:15 BST):**

After continued thought, I figured that Product Category pages typically consist of vertical internal links only; linking to the subsequent Child Category/Product page(s).

Could it be that some prefer to override a Product Category page, with a Standard page, so that they are able to 'horizontally' link to Blog Categories/Posts concerning the Product Category products?

I am not currently sure whether this is good practice or not, since you would have to break out from a Silo structure, but it is something I thought, which may lead to some people wanting to perform such an override.

Comment: Can you link to examples giving such advice?

Comment: Here is one example:  https://www.gobloggingtips.com/silo-structure-for-seo/#tab-con-11 5 Paragraphs down.

Comment: Thanks. The page doesn’t mention "static". What exactly do you mean with "static page" in this question? Usually the meaning is: a HTML page that doesn’t get generated by PHP or similar, i.e., a HTML document that exists as file on the server.

Comment: My apologies.  I did use the term 'static' incorrectly.  Referring to the example, it states to get WordPress 'Pages' to override WordPress 'Category' pages.  WordPress 'Pages' typically consisting of timeless content such as 'Contact Us' and 'About Us' etc.  Just trying to get some clarity really, within the context of Silos, since some use 'Pages' and 'Categories' interchangeable whilst others make a clear distinction between them both.  Personally, I just do not see any great benefit of overriding 'Category' pages with standard 'Pages'.

Comment: Search engines make no considerations that make a silo better than anything else. SEs rank pages individually without context to other pages short of links, URLs, and content. As far as URLs are concerned, they are hints. They are not clustered semantically that I have ever seen. In otherwords, pages and directories are not analyzed as being related based upon a URL. The semantic value of a URL is just too small to warrant further analysis. At least that I have seen. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc:  *not analyzed as being related based upon a URL* ... Not that it would be good practice but in theory, the URL could really be anything and provided the on page content and internal linking etc is all efficiently integrated, the URL structure would have a negligible effect?!